# How is this python code reading the csv file?

Tags: python, loops, iterator

Could anyone explain to me exactly what this code is saying in detail:

```
i = int(0)
L = list();
for row in reader:
    if i != 0: 
        tempNum = convertStr(row[3].replace(",", ""))
        L.append(tempNum)

    i += 1
f.close()

tempTotal = 0.0
for value in L:
    tempTotal += value
avgStrideDist = tempTotal / i
```

Comment: It's a bit hard to read, indent the code.

Comment: where did you ind this code?  We can not tell you what it is doing, because reader is not defined.  Did you find this from something like a python excel reader?

Comment: (a) Which part confuses you? (b) You haven't included the definition of all variables. In particular, `reader` is not defined in this code.

Comment: It's indented, but I don't know exactly what you're trying to say. Could you explain a bit?

Comment: It's helps if you provide a reader line example

Comment: I think something is missing. I see an `f.close()` but I don't see anything opening the file. Moreover, where the `reader` object is created?

Comment: Also, this code is terrible style.

Comment: its importing a csv file from excel.

Comment: @CraigHarrison: You can and should edit your question.

Answer (score 2):

This code is terrible style. You should read and understand a python tutorial. That said, I've rewritten it in a way that hopefully makes it easier to understand.

```
reader = ??? # seriously, where is it defined?
f = ??? # likewise, where?

# don't call it L ferchrissakes
next(reader) # ignore first element for whatever reason - this assumes reader is some kind of generator object
converted_strs = [convertStr(row[3].replace(",", "")) for row in reader] #what's convertStr??
f.close() # close the file object held in f, whatever it is.

total = sum(L)
avgStrideDist = float(total)/ len(converted_strs)
```

If the only thing you were doing with this data would be to calculate the mean, you might use something like `reduce` with a generator expression instead of a list comprehension, in order to avoid having to traverse the data twice; or perhaps you wouldn't, because this approach is easy to understand.

Comment: +1, although you've removed the subtle off-by-one error in the original, so your code isn't *quite* equivalent.

Comment: @Wooble: I'm explicitly ignoring the first element in `reader`. Is that the error you mean? Or is there another one (`row != len(L)`?)?

Comment: yeah, the original code adds 1 to the count used in the average even though it skips that line. granted, your version is probably what they *meant* to do...

Answer (score 0):

```
i = int(0)    # make an int and initialize it to 0. Equivalent to i=0
L = list();    # make a new empty list. Equivalent to L=[]. Semicolon is unnecessary but not wrong
for row in reader:    # I'm guessing there's a variable called reader initialized somewhere before
    if i != 0: # if the variable i contains any value other than 0
        tempNum = convertStr(row[3].replace(",", "")) # call an external function called convertStr (defined somewhere else) on the input parameter of the fourth item in a list called row (indexing starts at 0, so item at index 3 is the 4th item). Make sure that this item does not contain commas before giving it to convertStr. Assign the result to a variable called tempNum
        L.append(tempNum) # add the value of tempNum to the end of L

    i += 1 # increment i
f.close() # close the file that you were reading (I assume this was opened before)

# get the average of all the values in the list L
tempTotal = 0.0
for value in L:
    tempTotal += value
avgStrideDist = tempTotal / i
```

Basically, all of this is equivalent to:

```
total = sum(map(int, (i.replace(',', '') for i in reader)))
avgStrideDist = total/float(len(reader))
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks, this helps a lot. If i had more than 14 reputations points i would vote you up. Im new.

Comment: No sweat! Glad I could help. But you really need to work on phrasing your questions better. Follow the comments others have left on your question ;-)

Answer (score 0):

First off, this is not enough to provide all the details we need, but assuming that reader here is something like:

```
 f = open(filename)   
 reader = csv.reader(f, dialect='excel')
```

You can see more details here about the [csv.reader](http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html#csv.reader)

Now having this this piece of code:

```
 i = int(0)
 L = list();
 for row in reader:
    if i != 0: 
        tempNum = convertStr(row[3].replace(",", ""))
        L.append(tempNum)
    i += 1
```

This goes trough all the lines except the first one, splits the row and replaces ',' character in the 4'th element with '' and adds it to the list. This is ugly coding for python, you could rewrite this like:

```
 L = [row[3].replace(',', "") for row in lines[1:]]
```

or

```
 L = list()
 for idx, row in enumerate(reader):
     if idx:
          L.append(row[3].replace(',', '')
```

The rest is just an average on that resulting list. This can also be done in a more elegant way by simply doing:

```
 avg = sum(L) / len(L)
```